# CSV reader won't read correct column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

Me again sorry. So here's an example of the data I'm trying to read.

```
nhy, time, dt=    0  0.0000D+00  1.9416D-02
nhy, time, dt=    1  1.9400D-02  2.2416D-02
nhy, time, dt=    2  4.3800D-02  3.0416D-02
nhy, time, dt=    3  7.3540D-02  4.8416D-02
nhy, time, dt=    4  1.3350D-01  6.9416D-02
```

And I'm trying to extract the dt column with this code,

```
dt50 = []

file = "timestep.log"
col_list = ["dt"]
data = pd.read_csv(file, sep= '\s+|\t+|\s+\t+|\t+\s', skiprows = (30), usecols = col_list

dt50.extend(data['dt'])

print(dt50)
```

This all just returns the dt column not the actual value column. I'm guessing its to do with my declaring of the column I want but not sure where I'm going wrong.

Sorry for bothering you all with my lack of ability in coding.

Comment: Are you positive that your `csv` file is formatted correctly? The example you gave throws an error when you try to run it as there are no columns specified. Should your columns be: `nhy`, `time`, and `dt`?

Comment: There isnt an and in the log file that was generated. Theres some information above it hence why I added the 'skiprows' command but the data I'm using is output as shown above.

Comment: Yes, however, your code throws a `KeyError: "dt"` when that data is read. Is there a header in the original file? When you say, "...just returns the dt column not the actual value column." can you provide an example of what you want?

Comment: So instead of printing what in the data is the 3rd numerical column of 1.9416D-02, 2.2416D-02, 3.0416D-02 etc. it just prints out dt, dt, dt etc. so it reads the dt which is the column name not the actual values if you get what I mean.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I cannot reproduce the output you are getting because the code you have shared throws a `KeyError: "dt"` as there is no column "dt." Is there any chance you can share the entire file with us?

Comment: Hi heres a google drive link to the log file hope this is ok @gmdev
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JjRtECp2yHthhIw7XOikr1FDZwJ3C3J6/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only getting `dt` in your output because it is interpreting the first line of data as the columns. Therefore, the output data looks like this:

```
   nhy, time, dt =   0  0.0000D+00  1.9416D-02
0  nhy, time, dt =   1  1.9416D-02  2.4464D-02
1  nhy, time, dt =   2  4.3881D-02  3.0825D-02
2  nhy, time, dt =   3  7.4706D-02  3.8840D-02
3  nhy, time, dt =   4  1.1355D-01  4.8938D-02
4  nhy, time, dt =   5  1.6248D-01  6.1662D-02
5  nhy, time, dt =   6  2.2415D-01  7.7694D-02
6  nhy, time, dt =   7  3.0184D-01  9.7895D-02
7  nhy, time, dt =   8  3.9974D-01  1.2335D-01
8  nhy, time, dt =   9  5.2308D-01  1.5542D-01
9  nhy, time, dt =  10  6.7850D-01  1.9583D-01
```

As you can see, the columns are: `nhy,`, `time,`, `dt`, `=`, `0`, `0.0000D+00`, `1.9416D-02`. Thus, when you try to access the values by saying `data["dt"]`, the only data that resides under the column `"dt"` is just other string values of `"dt"`.

The issue here is your regex pattern. Your current regex pattern checks for the instances where it has any number of spaces and/or tabs. Because `nhy, time, dt =` are all separated by spaces and/or tabs, it's going to create columns for every element that is separated by a space. Let's replace this regex with `\s{2,}`, which is going to check for two or more spaces (the actual values are all separated uniquely by two spaces). We can then assign the columns their own names with `names=["nhy", "time", "dt"]`. Your `read_csv` line would then look something like this:

```
file = "timestep.log"
data = pd.read_csv(file, sep="\s{2,}", names=["nhy", "time", "dt"])
```

Which gives us:

```
                 nhy        time          dt
nhy, time, dt =    0  0.0000D+00  1.9416D-02
nhy, time, dt =    1  1.9416D-02  2.4464D-02
nhy, time, dt =    2  4.3881D-02  3.0825D-02
nhy, time, dt =    3  7.4706D-02  3.8840D-02
nhy, time, dt =    4  1.1355D-01  4.8938D-02
nhy, time, dt =    5  1.6248D-01  6.1662D-02
nhy, time, dt =    6  2.2415D-01  7.7694D-02
nhy, time, dt =    7  3.0184D-01  9.7895D-02
nhy, time, dt =    8  3.9974D-01  1.2335D-01
nhy, time, dt =    9  5.2308D-01  1.5542D-01
```

Now we have all of the data in their respective columns. All we have to do is reset the index, which is currently `nhy, time, dt =`:

```
data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Which gives us:

```
    nhy        time          dt
0     0  0.0000D+00  1.9416D-02
1     1  1.9416D-02  2.4464D-02
2     2  4.3881D-02  3.0825D-02
3     3  7.4706D-02  3.8840D-02
4     4  1.1355D-01  4.8938D-02
5     5  1.6248D-01  6.1662D-02
6     6  2.2415D-01  7.7694D-02
7     7  3.0184D-01  9.7895D-02
8     8  3.9974D-01  1.2335D-01
9     9  5.2308D-01  1.5542D-01
```

Now all that's left to do is extend your existing list:

```
dt50.extend(data["dt"].tolist())
```

Which gives us the desired output:

```
['1.9416D-02', '2.4464D-02', '3.0825D-02', '3.8840D-02', '4.8938D-02', '6.1662D-02', '7.7694D-02', '9.7895D-02', '1.2335D-01', '1.5542D-01']
```

Comment: Thank you so much this really helped me!